# how to sort HashMap by value in descending order

Tags: sorting, hashmap

I have this code , but it is sorting hashMap by value in ascending order , I want to to sort HashMap in descending order.

```
public  Map<String, Float> sortByValue(Map<String, Float> map) {
List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
     public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
          return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
         .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
     }
});

   Map result = new LinkedHashMap();
   for (Iterator it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
       Map.Entry entry = (Map.Entry)it.next();
       result.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
   }

   return result;
}
```

for example my hash map :

> ("word",0.7) , ("word2",1.0)

I want to to be orders like :

> ("word2",1.0) , ("word,0.7")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can invert the order by inverting the result of the `compareTo`-Method.

```
 public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
      return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
     .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
 }
```

would change to

```
 public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
      return -((Comparable) ((Map.Entry) (o1)).getValue())
     .compareTo(((Map.Entry) (o2)).getValue());
 }
```

This turns a 1 into a -1 and vica versa, leading to the inverted order.